# Eclipse CDT Indexer not including header from same project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

After a recent upgrade (only SSD capacity change), Eclipse CDT Indexer has been giving me a tough time. My project folder structure is as shown below.

```
LinEmLibrary
└─ test
   ├─ TestNumParam.cpp
   ├─ TestNumParam.h
   ├─ TestPMS.cpp
   ├─ TestPMS.h
   ├─ TestSerial.cpp
   ├─ TestSerial.h
   ├─ TestWindow.cpp
   └─ TestWindow.h
```

`TestWindow.h` has the class implementing the top level window and the other three are instantiated by the class `CTestWindow`.

After the upgrade (until which things were running perfectly), Codan (code analysis) started highlighting the declarations of all of my class instances (`CTestNUmParam`, `CTestPMS` and `CTestSerial`) in red saying *Type X could not be resolved*. However I am able to perform code completion (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>) and resolve all members of the class though it takes a painfully long amount of time. **The code builds and executes properly**.

I have tried

- rebuilding the index
- Increased the Indexer cache limits (*Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer - Cache limits*) to,

  - Limit relative to the maximum heap size: 75%
  - Absolute limit: 1024 MB
- Set the initial and maximum heap size in `eclipse.ini` to

  - Xms2048m
  - Xmx4096m
- adding absolute path to this folder in the *Project Settings > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols* and even include my header using <> instead of ""
- create a new project and manually copy the files to the new project
- export the project and open in another computer having same build tools

But in all cases the result is the same.

When I create a parse log for `TestWIndow.h` (right click on the header file in project explorer, *Index > Create Parser Log File*) I get the following output (first ~12,000 lines removed).

```
Unresolved includes (from headers in index):
   file:/home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestNumParam.h is not indexed
   file:/home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestPMS.h is not indexed
   file:/home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestSerial.h is not indexed

Unresolved names:
   Attempt to use symbol failed: CTestNumParam in file /home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestWindow.h:76
   Attempt to use symbol failed: CTestPMS in file /home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestWindow.h:77
   Attempt to use symbol failed: CTestSerial in file /home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestWindow.h:78
   A template id provides illegal arguments for the instantiation: map in file /home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestWindow.h:80
   Attempt to use symbol failed: EGridType in file /home/mohith/eclipse_workspace/LinEmLibrary/test/TestWindow.h:80
```

The reason for the semantic highlighting is now understood from this but why the indexer is not including my own header files leaves me clueless.

Would be a great help if someone can shed some light.

My system information

```
Eclipse
  Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
  Build id: 20210910-1417
  CDT: 10.4.0.202109080104
OS  Ubuntu 20.04 x86-64
RAM: 16 GiB
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month of struggle I have finally broght things back to normal.

The issue appears to be the *preferences* I would import after creating a new workspace. I have exported preferences once after setting up the environment for code style, editor font / color etc. I don't remember exactly but I might have created it while running Eclipse 2021-03.

This time I created a new workspace and added the project from SVN without importing preferences and viola... all my headers are indexed! Later I individually exported the code style and other templates and brought it into my new workspace without any issues.

I was also facing issue with Log4CPlus where all its macros were marked as 'symbol not resolved'. Upon inspecting the parser log file I saw that the symbol `__cplusplus` was set to `201402` even though I had selected c++20 as the dialect in build settings. Then I added the symbol `__cplusplus` manully in *Project Settings > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Symbols > GNU C++* while settings it to 202002. That fixed the issue with Log4CPlus as well.